# Different result in IIS express and IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008, dotnetnuke, iis-express

I recently installed webmatrix on a windows 2008 machine.
I installed dotnetnuke using webmatrix, I visited the site using a browser on the server, finished installing the site, and everything works just fine.

I than created a site in IIS, and pointed it at the folder where I installed dotnetnuke.

When I visit the site using my domain name and on port 80 with a browser on my server, it takes me to the install page. When I visit the site using a remote computer, it says "This site is currently Unavailable Please check back later". Yet, when I visit it on iis express, it works perfectly!.

What is wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the site alias section to make sure that it is picking up on the altered url? Also, I have personally had a lot of issues when the application is not in the root directory of the web server.

Comment: This could be a basic issue in IIS site/application mapping. There IS already a default site in IIS. You should have created a new site, bind it to a custom header (`my.site.com`) and point it to the folder with dotnetnuke. Then add a local DNS entry (/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) and point to 127.0.0.1 so you can access your local site with the custom header in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things that could be going on at this point.

1. Incorrect permissions - Ensure that the ASP.NET Worker Process has full permissions to the DotNetNuke directory.  (With IIS Express, you are using your user account IIRC)
2. Incorrect database access - Ensure that the connection information is correct for the database.  As with the above, if the connection for example has a "Integrated Security=true" option defined, you will need to either change this to a SQL account or add the ASP.NET worker Process user to have permissions
3. It could be a missing Portal Alias, but the current versions of DNN don't have the same issue as you use to.
4. ALso make sure that the UsePortNumber option in the web.config is set to false.